# Dimension in SQL Analysis Server not unique in hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I have created a Dimension in Analysis-Server like with the following hierarchy:

```
CountryRegion
StateProvince
City
PersonName
```

with the following relationship

```
DimCustomerID -> PersonName -> City -> StateProvince -> CountryRegion
```

Now, my Data for this dimenstion contains the following rows:

```
DimCustomerID   CustomerID  AddressID   CountryRegion   StateProvince   City        PersonName
4134            13788       19569       United Kingdom  England         Birmingham  Fernandez Kari
4717            11533       18752       United States   Alabama         Birmingham  Gill Ebony
```

When I try to process the Dimension, I get the error

```
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing: Table: 'BI_DimCustomer', Column: 'City', Value: 'Birmingham'. The attribute is 'City'.
```

I see, that the City Birmingham is duplicated with differen StateProvince. But they also have two different CountryRegions.

What can I do to get this running?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the KeyColumns for the City Attribute.  Eg (CountryRegion,StateProvince,City).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/dimension-attribute-properties-reference

See eg
http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1887/ssas-understanding-keycolumns-dimension-property

David